# Uniform convergence of $x^n$ using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I have been trying to prove the uniform convergence of sequence of functions defined by $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,k]$ where $k<1$ by the epsilon definition of uniform convergence.

I have found the point-wise limit of the same..i.e. $f(x)=0$

Now let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Then if the given sequence is uniformly convergent then we must have that there exists a natural number $m$ such that $|x^n-0|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq m$ and for all $x$ in $[0,k]$, which on further calculations give that $$n>\frac{\log(1/\epsilon)}{\log(1/x)}$$
Now what natural number $m$ should I choose such that for all $n\geq m$ the above holds?

Please help!

Comment: Hint: Observe that $x \in [0,k]$ so $|x^n-0|=|x^n| \leq |k^n|$. So if you choose $m=\frac{\log \varepsilon}{\log k}$ then...

Comment: $m$ should not depend on $x$. it depends only on $\epsilon$.

Comment: $|f_n(x)-0|=x^n <k^n$; $\epsilon >0$ given. Since $k<1$, $\lim_{n} k^n=0$, there exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $n\ge n_0$: $k^n <\epsilon$.

Comment: Please use math mode to write all relevant math symbols (don't put equals signs, absolute value bars, etc outside the dollar signs when writing equations). I have upgraded your post with this change.

Comment: Where is the math mode..n how to get the absolute value bar?..I didn't understand ..what equal sign outside the dollar sign are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we begin by observing that
$$\forall x\in[0,k]\;\; |x^n|\le k^n$$

given $\epsilon>0$.
we just need to find $ m\ge 0$ such that

$$n\ge m \implies k^n<\epsilon$$
or
$$n\ge m \;\implies n\ln(k)<\ln(\epsilon)$$

which gives
$$n\ge m \;\implies n>\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(k)}$$

we know that
$$\lfloor \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(k)}\rfloor +1>\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(k)}$$
so, we can take for example
$$m=\lfloor \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(k)}\rfloor +3$$

Comment: Thank you so much